# How do I convert Japanese full-width numbers to half-width numbers?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, replace

I want to convert Japanese full-width number to half-width number using React.

### My attempt so far

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");

  const convertFullWidthToHalfWidth = (str) => {
    const fullWidth =
      "\uff10\uff11\uff12\uff13\uff14\uff15\uff16\uff17\uff18\uff19";
    const halfWidth = "0123456789";
    return str.replace(new RegExp("[" + fullWidth + "]", "g"), (match) => {
      return halfWidth.charAt(fullWidth.indexOf(match));
    });
  };

  const onChange = (e) => {
    const v = convertFullWidthToHalfWidth(e.target.value);
    console.log(v);
    setValue(v);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input value={value} onChange={onChange} />
      <h2>{value}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

### Problem

Input (full-width number):

"１２"

Expected result (half-width number):

"12"

Actual result (half-width number):

"112"

What is the problem in my code?

Comment: "*but it doesn't work as expected*" - What are you expecting? What is not working? Please provide more information - [ask]